# can we show content of datalist in input field rather than it's value

Tags: html, input, html-datalist

I want my calculation to run without showing it to the person using it so I want him to see only the content of input option, not value
example:
`<option value="66.48">25 LIGHT</option>`
when someone select this option his input field should show **25 LIGHT** instead of 666.48.
NOTE: I cant use **select**, I have to use **datalist** because I want the user to get options by typing, as there are 100s of them. can I do this with data list?
please guide.

my code:

```
  <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="    totalamount.value = Math.round(((Item.value * Quantity.value - (Item.value * Quantity.value *Percentage.value /100))+ Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 ;">
Percentage<input name="Percentage" id="Percentage" type="number">
<br />
<section class="container">
 <div class="one">
  Item<br/><input list="items" type="text" name="Item" id="Item" width="70%">
 </div>

 <div class="two">
  Quantity <br/><input name="Quantity" id="Quantity" type="number">
 </div>
</section>
<br/>
Total amount <output name="totalamount" id="totalamount" for="Item Quantity Percentage"></output>
</form>
<datalist id="items">
<option value="66.48">25 LIGHT</option>
<option value="88.64">25 MEDIUM</option>
<option value="103.41">25 HEAVY</option>
<option value="93.54">Regal 19/1.0</option>
<option value="69.8">Regal 19/1.2</option>
<option value="69.8">Regal 19/1.4</option> </datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selectedIndex` property of the select field to get the selected `<option>` element as a node. Then get the `innerHTML` of that node:

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");
select.onchange = function() {
  var html = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML
  console.log(html);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

In case you are using a `<datalist>`, you need to manually lookup the option whose value matches the value of your `<datalist>`:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var list = document.getElementById("nums");

input.onchange = function() {
  var selected = Array.from(list.options).filter(opt => {
    return opt.value == input.value;
  })[0];
  console.log(selected.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<input list="nums"/>

<datalist id="nums">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant use select, I have to use datalist because I want the user to get options by typing, as there are 100s of them. can I do this with data list?